# Create Test data within business hour and outside of business hours?

Tags: apex, unit-test, businesshours

I have below code and for that I am trying to write the test classes. As per code look like Case should be created within Business hours and other condition says that, case should be created outside of business hours.

How can we cover the `else` block?

```
global static DateTime getEndDate(DateTime startDateTime, Integer bDays){
    BusinessHours bh1 = [SELECT Id,Name,IsActive,IsDefault,MondayEndTime,MondayStartTime 
                            FROM BusinessHours 
                            WHERE Name = 'Default Business Hours'];

    //if case creation is outside business hours                      
    if(!BusinessHours.isWithin(bh1.id,startDateTime)){
        for(integer i=0; i<bDays; i++){
            startDateTime = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh1.id,startDateTime);
            startDateTime = startDateTime.addminutes(721);
        }  
          startDateTime = startDateTime.addminutes(-721);
    }
    //if case creation is inside business hours 
    else{
        for(integer i=0; i<bDays; i++){
            startDateTime = startDateTime.addminutes(721);
            startDateTime = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh1.id,startDateTime);
        }
    }
    return startDateTime ;
}
```

Here is the test class

```
static testMethod void testGetEndDate(){
        Test.startTest();
        Date today = Date.today();

        // outside of Business Hours
        DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(today.year(), today.month(), today.day(), 2, 2, 3);
        DateTime response = BusinessDayUtil.getEndDate(startDateTime, 7); 
        System.assert(response != null);


        //within business Hours
        DateTime nstartDateTime = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(today.year(), today.month(), today.day(), 11, 11, 11);
        DateTime nresponse = BusinessDayUtil.getEndDate(nstartDateTime, 10);
        System.assert(nresponse != null);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: one a idea: create a bool property in your class: BusinessHour. Test if a test is running. If yes, get the Property, if not get from System variable. Set the property in the test class.

Comment: Could you please post some code to support your answer ?

Comment: I do not understand where your problem lies... you seem to be properly testing for both inside and outside of business hours....

Comment: You're creating times in GMT. Make sure that your business hours are actually in the correct time zone. You may need to do some calculations.

Comment: N.B. Your PROD code is sensitive to the BusinessHours name. Perhaps you should be querying where `IsDefault = true`